# Setting multiple literals that contain the same text in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I have instances where I need to dynamically load 5-10 literals with the same text value.  It seems like there has to be a more elegant way of doing it than setting the TEXT property of all the controls to the same value.  Any methods out there that I'm not aware of?  I thought about setting a protected property on my webform, and then using inline code on my aspx page.  Is that a good approach?

Edit: I should add that I also want to handle the situation where a designer could simply add another place to load dynamically to the aspx file on the web server without having to do another rollout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When faced with the same problem I often use:

```
litOne.Text = litTwo.Text = litThree.Text = "some value";
```

It's not perfect but at least it's on one line.

Comment: +1 while i think this is generally an acceptable solution to this problem, i must say tho, "it's not perfect but at least it's on one line" is not a very good programming idiom =)

Answer (score 2):

Pseudo code:

```
var literals = new List<Literal>() { l1,l2,l3 ...} ;
literals.ForEach(x=>x.Text = "some value");
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
foreach (ITextControl textControl in new[] { literal1, literal2, literal3 })
{
    textControl.Text = "foo";
}
```

You could even be fancier and just loop through all controls and check only those that implement the ITextControl interface or so.